# Update template when scope is changed

Tags: angularjs

I have a template in which I output the values (movie titles) from my database,

```
%div{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies"}
  {{ movie.title }}
```

And a template in which users can input a movie title,

```
%div{"ng-controller" => "searchCtrl", :id => "container_search"}
  #addMovie{"ng-controller" => "addMovieCtrl"}
    %div{"ng-click" => "addMovie()"}
      %input{:type => "text", "ng-model" => "title"}
      addMovie action.
```

When a user types in a movie title in the inputfield and clicks the div it gets saved into the database, and when I refresh the page I can see the result. But I want this to happen asynchronously (at the same time, right?).

This is the controller,

```
angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .controller('movieOverviewCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'movieService', function($scope, movieService) {

      movieService.success(function(data) {
        $scope.movies = data;
      });
    }
  ]);
```

And this is the service,

```
angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('movieService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.get('movies.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        return data;
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        return err;
      });
  }])

  .factory('movies', ['$http', function($http){
    var o = {
      movies: []
    };

    o.create = function(movie){
      return $http.post('/movies.json', movie).success(function(data){
        o.movies.push(data);
      });
    };

    return o;

  }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service should not do an HTTP request as soon as it's instanciated, and then always return the same result. Instead, it should provide a method that allows getting the movies.

Once that is done, you can simply call the service again right after saving a new movie:

```
angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('movieService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
      loadMovies: function() {
        return $http.get('movies.json');
      }
    };
  }])

  .factory('movies', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
      create: function(movie) {
        return $http.post('/movies.json', movie);
      }
    };
  }]);
```

and your controller can now simply do

```
angular.module('addMovieseat')
  .controller('movieOverviewCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'movieService', 'movies', function($scope, movieService, movies) {

     var init = function() {
       movieService.loadMovies().then(function(response) {
         $scope.movies = response.data;
       });
     };
     init();

     $scope.save = function() {
       movies.create({title: $scope.title}).then(init);
     };
  }]);
```

Note that you're making your own life more complex than it should by defining two services instead of just one that would have a `loadMovies()` and a `create()` functions.

Comment: Yea it's a little bit of a Frankenstein code at the moment. Going to clean it up when I get the prototype result. You're advice helped me out! Had to fix a few things, but with the great example and tips I finished it.